# Unity path tracing makes the pc crash

Tags: raytracing, pathtracing, compute-shader, hlsl, unity

Good Morning. I'm testing Path Tracing techniques with unity, following this tutorial.
http://three-eyed-games.com/2019/03/18/gpu-path-tracing-in-unity-part-3/
But I'm in trouble.

Whenever I try to run the compute shader it crashes the system.

I was erasing some lines and found that the problem happens when I try to change the values ​​of the hit.

```
    void IntersectMeshObject(int index, CameraRay ray, inout CameraRayHit bestHit)
{
    int offset = _Objects[index].indices_offset;
    int count = offset + _Objects[index].indices_count;

    for (int i = offset; i < count; i += 3)
    {
       float3 v0 = (mul(_Objects[index].localToWorldMatrix, float4(_Vertices[_Indices[i]], 1))).xyz;
       float3 v1 = (mul(_Objects[index].localToWorldMatrix, float4(_Vertices[_Indices[i + 1]], 1))).xyz;
       float3 v2 = (mul(_Objects[index].localToWorldMatrix, float4(_Vertices[_Indices[i + 2]], 1))).xyz;

       float t, u, v;

        if (IntersectTriangle(ray, v0, v1, v2, t, u, v))
        {
            if (t > 0 && t < bestHit.rayHitDistance)
            {
                bestHit.rayHitDistance = t; //<--That makes it crash
                bestHit.rayHitPosition = ray.raySource + t * ray.rayDirection;//<--That makes it crash
                bestHit.rayHitNormal = float3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);//<--That makes it crash

                bestHit.viewDirection = normalize(_WorldSpaceCameraPos - bestHit.rayHitPosition);//<--That makes it crash
                bestHit.lightDirection = _DirectionalLightDirection;//<--That makes it crash

                bestHit.rayHitAlbedo = float4(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1);//<--That makes it crash
                bestHit.rayHitEmission = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);//<--That makes it crash
                bestHit.rayHitSmoothness = 0.6;//<--That makes it crash
                bestHit.rayHitMetallic = 0.6;//<--That makes it crash
                bestHit.rayHitAnisotropy = 0;//<--That makes it crash

                bestHit.hitRenderType = 0;//<--That makes it crash
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

When executing only with sphere hits
[image]

When I leave the if without instructions it works normally.

All codes:
https://gist.github.com/MatheusMarkies/3a334b97d3ee4330c335143e496ded67

Can someone help me find out where the problem is?

Comment: Doing some tests I found that the error is in this FOR.
Probably the way I'm saving the mesh information is wrong, but I don't know why.

Comment: The inout variable bestHit is most likely not valid, reads will usually work, but writes will cause a crash. The caller my be over running the buffer, or some other code may be stepping on bestHit and creating a wild reference.